# how to resign a single macro

Tags: macros, kentico, signature

I'm new to Kentico and I'm testing out CI and staging. I was messing around with a macro identities and I think I broke something.
I since removed the macro Identity and reset the administrator user (I had assigned it a macro identity user). I had also changed the salt value at some point.

So I resigned all my macro's using system > macros > signatures.
Sadly the macros report stil shows a bunch of (almost all) invalid signatures.

I particularly have an issue in the staging > servers tab, where I get a unigrid reload issue.
The eventlog contains the following macro error. After checking the report it is one of the macro's with an invalid signature.
How can I resign/fix these issues, or what am I missing that the resign tool isn't effective?

[image]

PS: this is a blank, local test site so it isn't really important for the site itself. I just want to learn where I messed up, before installing a new blank site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resigning ALL macros make sure you have a CMSHashSalt key in your web.config.  This value should not change from environment to environment . Also, when resigning ALL macros make sure you have checked both boxes under System>Macros>Signatures.

Lastly if you want to resign just one macro you need to just open the page or object the macro is on and re-save it.

Comment: Hi Brenden. Thanks for answering another question. the problem was I hadn't checked the first checkbox, "sign all macro's". As this disables the old salt input box and I had changed the salt, I thought I had to enter it.